# Troubleshooting log4net FileAppender

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, log4net-configuration

We've been using log4net for some time, but occasionally have problems with the logger failing to roll over (typically for our services) on a daily basis. This causes major headaches, as it means we lose our logging without warning and have to check every day to see if the logging was successful or not.

I finally enabled the log4net debugging, and have been consistently getting this error from our WCF service (which handles all DAL calls) every morning the first time someone tries to hit the service.

```
log4net: FileAppender: Opening file for writing 
[C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.20160129.txt] append [False]
log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] Unable to acquire lock on file C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.20160129.txt. Access to the path 'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.20160129.txt' is denied.
log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] OpenFile(C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx,False) call failed.
System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable.
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
   at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.OpenFile(String fileName, Boolean append)
   at log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.OpenFile(String fileName, Boolean append)
   at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.SafeOpenFile(String fileName, Boolean append)
log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] Failed in DoAppend
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: writer
   at log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.RenderLoggingEvent(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
```

Our log4net configuration is as follows.

```
<log4net debug="false">
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d] [%-5p] [%logger]: %m%n------------------------------------------------------------------%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="File" value="C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyyMMdd.\t\x\t"/>
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d] [%-5p] [%logger]: %m%n------------------------------------------------------------------%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <to value="xxx@yyy.com"/>
      <from value="xxx@yyy.com"/>
      <subject value="Error Occurred in xxx Service"/>
      <smtpHost value="xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
      <bufferSize value="512"/>
      <lossy value="true"/>
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="Error"/>
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <!--ALL -> DEBUG -> INFO -> WARN -> ERROR -> FATAL -> OFF-->
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="SmtpLog">
      <!--ALL -> DEBUG -> INFO -> WARN -> ERROR -> FATAL -> OFF-->
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

This same basic pattern works wonderfully for our web applications (ASP.NET) and Winforms applications, but seems to be consistently failing day over day.

If we restart the service it immediately picks up logging without a hitch. Is this a permissions issue for the destination folder? The source folder? Or something else entirely?

I should also mention that the user the service is running under has full access to the directory we're writing our logfiles to.

Comment: Have you tried checking who's locked the file at the time of failure?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: If it works for you ASP.NET and Winforms and don't for WCF, then probably there's a permission issue with the user running the WCF?

Comment: The user running the WCF has full access to the destination folder.

Comment: @Marisa you can use `Process Explorer` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx  or any other tool like `wholockme` or `unlocker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you do not trust that top level permissions go all the way down.

It turns out that the folder hierarchy we use is something like the following:
`c:\GROUP_NAME\APPLICATION_NAME\SERVICE_FOLDER` and `c:\GROUP_NAME\APPLICATION_NAME\WEB_APPLICATION_FOLDER`.

The service user had access permission at `C:`, `GROUP_NAME`, and `APPLICATION_NAME`, but critically, *not at `SERVICE_FOLDER`*. I've updated the permissions to include explicit permission for the service user at the SERVICE_FOLDER level, which I fully expect will resolve the issue.